# When the server receives a request, does it automatically knows the website is itself?

Tags: web-server

My website URL is modified for access from remote systems like this:

```
//var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/dosomething"
var url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/dosomething"
```

The URL is used by the Python backend and JS front end.  When the server receives a request, does it automatically know `www.somewebsite.com` is itself?

Comment: The hostname the browser used is available to your web application. If you need it for some reason, you would have to explicitly write code to get its value. How you do that varies depending on the language and framework you are using.

Comment: Unless this is a "I have no clue what I do" - you really need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It knows automatically when it receives this detail in the Host field of [the HTTP request header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields). But as a server can be called by just its IP, this is not always the case. So you need to know the agent.

You should remember though an IP can host multiple [virtual hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) and there is no one-to-one mapping between a domain and an IP. In fact it can be even many-to-many.

Comment: At the moment, the PC only hosts that website and it's not behind NginX or Apache Tomcat.  Say if I want to host multiple websites on it behind NginX using the server blocks (virtual hosts), what changes are required make it work?

Comment: @CaTx Again, you would have to write code in your application. We cannot help you with that.

Comment: If you have multiple sites you parse the URL on the front end to direct the request. Typically serve a nice error page if the URL doesn't match.

Comment: @CaTx Domain names lay at the basis of virtual hosts - beside IPs. Just try what you want and see what happens. It may just work. If you have problems, post new questions describing them.